# Persisting api data on client after fetching at build time with gatsby and netlify

Tags: gatsby, netlify, jamstack

New to Gatsby and Netlify but I have a question that I can't find answer to elsewhere, possibly because it's the wrong approach.

I'm building a weather app for a client that needs to show an animated view of the last day/week/months data which requires making multiple requests to the weather API for the data at different resolutions and then plugging that into the visualisations with a setInterval essentially.

Rather than making all these requests on the client, it occurred to me, I could get all the data at build time with a scheduled build and serve the page statically with this updated data each day which would save hammering the API and reduce costs.

The problem is gatsby assumes you want to generate html with fetched data and use createPages but here I just want to store the data as json in the js bundle for rendering on the client.

Is there a way to put the build time fetched and formatted data into json or similar and serve statically for rendering on the client?

Comment: Hi, the Gatsby docs  have a series if API calls you can hook into at different parts of the build/start process.  See https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged this question with the jamstack tag and your approach fits exactly into this approach.

> Is there a way to put the build time fetched and formatted data into
>   json or similar and serve statically for rendering on the client?

Yes.

1. Build your React code that shows the weather data.
2. Build your weather data json.
3. Use only variables from your weather data json.

Simple example:

```
import data from "./data/weatherData.json"

const WeatherApp = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>{data.title}</h1>
      <div>{data.rain}</div>
      <div>{data.temperature}</div>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

In order to populate the weather data you could build a complicated GraphQL query that fetches all the data exactly the way you need it.

One other approach would be to build your own API for example with AWS lamba or similar serverless free service and serve your weather data with that. This way you would not need to trigger the `gatsby build`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm reassured I'm barking up the right tree now and your last comment is somthing I hadn't thought of. I was planning to use a Netlify function to serve the live data anyway and handle the api credentials so could make a separate function for combining the historical data though this would only be called by the automatic daily build process anyway so may be same difference to put it together with gatsby at build time.. Something to think about though. Cheers!

I am loving JAMStack so far anyway

Comment: Awesome! You can accept this answer to have solved your question by clicking the checkmark so people won't stumble upon your solved question. =)

Comment: Cool, so my next question is specific to Netlify but will add here in case: now that I've created a Netlify lambda function that fetches the data I need for the build. How do I ensure it's available at build time? It seems to me that Netlify runs build before processing the functions folder so the endpoint is not available at build time for pulling the data in from..